# How to insert an item in a list, which includes hierarchical ObservableCollections (c#)

Tags: c#, list, recursion, insert, hierarchy

I have a list with hierarchical data in it and I want to update/edit an item which is in there, regardless of the hierarchy level.

The item can be found by a property called "`IsSelected`". I tried it with a recursive function, which returns the selected item. But now the question is how can I update the original item in my list?

I see myself in a vicious circle, where I can find the item I search for, which for I have to search again because I have to update my original item of the list and so on.

Well until now I can't escape. Any help is appreciated how to solve this the right way.

**Hierarchy example of the objects**

- Plantobject1

  - Plantobject1

    - Plantobject1
  - Plantobject2
  - Plantobject3

    - Plantobject1

      - Plantobject1  <-- how to edit this Plantobject or add a PO here

**Given**

```
public static List<PlantObject> PlantObjects { get; set; }
```

**Recursive Method**

```
public static PlantObject TryInsertPlantObject(ref PlantObject parentObject, ref PlantObject childObject)
{
    // Stop if subjects are null or empty

    if (childObject.IsSelected == true)
    {
        parentObject.PlantObjects.Add(new PlantObject { ObjectID = Guid.NewGuid().ToClientId().GetBytes(), Name = "new plant object", Type = "my type" });
        return parentObject;
    }

    if (childObject.PlantObjects.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var x in TryInsertPlantObject(ref parentObject, ref childObject))
        {
            if (x.IsSelected == true)
            {
                childObject.PlantObjects.Add(new PlantObject { ObjectID = Guid.NewGuid().ToClientId().GetBytes(), Name = "new plant object", Type = "my type" });
                return childObject;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Insert Method**

```
private void InsertAboveObject()
{

    PlantObject updatedPlantObject = new PlantObject();

    foreach (PlantObject plantObject in PlantObjects)
    {
        if (plantObject.IsSelected == true)
        {
            PlantObjects.Insert(
                PlantObjects.IndexOf(plantObject),
                new PlantObject
                    {
                        ObjectID = Guid.NewGuid()
                            .ToClientId()
                            .GetBytes(),
                        Name = "new plant object",
                        Type = "my type"
                    });
            return;
        }
    }

    foreach (PlantObject plantObject in PlantObjects)
    {
        foreach (PlantObject childObject in plantObject)
        {
            PlantObject _plantObject = plantObject;
            PlantObject _childObject = childObject;
            updatedPlantObject = TryInsertPlantObject(ref _plantObject, ref _childObject);
            if (updatedPlantObject != null) return;
        }
    }
}
```

**My Class**

```
public class PlantObject
{
    public PlantObject()
    {
    }

    private bool _IsSelected;

    public byte[] ParentID { get; set; }
    public byte[] ChildID { get; set; }
    public byte[] ObjectID { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<PlantObject> plantObjects = new ObservableCollection<PlantObject>();

    public ObservableCollection<PlantObject> PlantObjects
    {
        get { return plantObjects; }
        set
        {
            //ignore if values are equal
            if (value == plantObjects) return;

            plantObjects = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_IsSelected == value) return;
            _IsSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by update it?

Comment: I want to edit the item. Simply change some properties for example. Therefore I have to know the indices. Furthermore I want to insert items at this specific position, which is then nearly the same procedure.

Comment: If you want to notify that the collection has changed you should handle the CollectionChanged event, rather than PropertyChanged event.

Comment: I think I don't want to notify that the collection has changed? At least I don't get how this could help with my problem. Could you explain that in more detail please?